# Middle alignment icon+text in a div

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I need to center vertically in a square link an icon and a text below.

[image]

Here the example:

**Html:**

```
<div id="button1">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x"></i>
    <br/>Demo Primary <br />Button
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-sq-lg 
{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fabioravizzotti/hutmay1r/3/

I need that the icon and the text are centered into the square.

I tried many solution: `vertical-align`, `line-height` but they didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), as in the below Snippet. Don't forget to prefix the Flexbox properties as necessary.

**NOTE:** The `.btn` class is only required in the selector if the Bootsrap files are included in your HTML *after* your own stylesheet.

```css
.btn.btn-sq-lg{
    align-items:center;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="button1">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x"></i>
        <br>Demo Primary<br>Button
    </a>
</div>
```

By the way, you could achieve this with just a single tag, if you prefer, like so:

```css
#button1{
    background:#337ab7;
    border:1px solid #2e6da4;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    align-items:center;
    color:#fff;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    justify-content:center;
    line-height:20px;
    padding:6px 12px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
#button1::before{
    content:"\f007";
    display:block;
    font-family:FontAwesome;
    font-size:5em;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1;
    margin:0 0 20px;
}
#button1:active,#button1:hover{
    background:#286090;
    border-color:#204d74;
}
#button1:focus{
    background:#204d74;
    border-color:#122b40;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a id="button1" href="#">Demo Primary Button</a>
```

Comment: Why don't they implement external resources? What do you wanna add?

Comment: They add the `link` tags to the `body` of the Snippet, when they should be added to the `head` tag, before the `style` tag, if present. Because they come after the `style` tag currently, they will override styles set in the rules of the `style` tag, as Boostrap has with my CSS above.

Comment: Oh! Wait? Lemme check?

Comment: Can I suggest a change? Revert back if you don't feel it right!

Comment: I s'pose that'll do as a hack for now until they fix the Snippets, thanks :) I'm in no way familiar with Bootsrap so it would have taken me a while to figure it out.

Comment: That's not a hack. That's specificity! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `vertical-align` doesn't work is because it is a complex object (two elements). You need to do with positioning. I have added an extra `<span>` tag for containing them and using positioning, I fixed it:

```css
.btn-sq-lg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
#button1 a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
#button1 a span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="button1">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-primary">
    <span>
      <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x"></i>
      <br/>Demo Primary
      <br />Button
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

[image]

No matter what resolution or height, the `<span>` will be centred vertically and horizontally inside the `<a>` tag. See below for a longer text:

```css
.btn-sq-lg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
#button1 a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
#button1 a span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="button1">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-primary">
    <span>
      <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x"></i>
      <br/>Demo Primary
      <br />Button
      <br />Line
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution

```
<i class="fa fa-user fa-5x" style="margin-top: 31px;"></i>
```

Comment: Er... That seems to be a hackjob!